# Magento 2: Can't access admin panel after changing user account

Tags: magento2, admin-user

I get an error that the enter key 0 in admin_session is duplicated. So I just created a new user account and when I try to connect to panel admin with the new account I get this error [image]

I am really dead if I do not resolve this today please help

Comment: enable the admin user if disable, flush the cache and open in private window or else create new user.

Comment: it's enabled but can't access

Comment: Exception #1 (Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\DuplicateException): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `admin_user_session` (`session_id`, `user_id`, `status`, `ip`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: Create new admin user and try again.

Comment: how to resolve this please

Comment: can' i delete the content of table admin_user_session

Comment: Yes you can flush admin_user_session table.

Comment: You can create new admin user using  command php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user='new-user' --admin-password='admin123' --admin-email='admin@admin.com' --admin-firstname='Admin' --admin-lastname='Admin'

Comment: so i can delete the whole content without any trouble*

Comment: Manually flush the entrees.